# Delphi SQLite3 using ZeosLib, how to create a database and a table?

Tags: database, delphi, sqlite

I want create a database and a table programmatically with my Delphi Program on Windows 7 using Zeoslib component. From what I have found online so far, Zeoslib is expecting database to be created before using it. If so, is there a way to create a database and a table using Zeoslib tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normal this question will be closed because you did not show what have you tried so far.

With ZeosLib it's easy

**Safety Note:**
Of course you should use parameterized queries. only in order to simplify the procedure, it has been omitted here

Create the Database

```
procedure TForm1.CreateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ZConnection1.Protocol:='sqlite-3';
  ZConnection1.Database:='F:\Programme\stack\SQLite\Database.sqlite';
  ZConnection1.Connect;
  ZConnection1.Disconnect;
end;
```

Create a Table and Insert

```
procedure TForm1.CreateInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE hardware (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, compname VARCHAR(30), username VARCHAR(30), model VARCHAR(30))';
    ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
    ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'CREATE INDEX sHardware ON hardware(compname)';
    ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
    ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO hardware(id, compname, username, model) VALUES (1, "AMD8537", "OMonge", "Gigabyte");';
    ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
end;
```

To see Values Connect again

```
procedure TForm1.ConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ZConnection1.Connect;
end;
```

Show Values

```
procedure TForm1.OpenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT id, compname FROM hardware';
    ZQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Form

[image]

Running

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If database file does not exists - SQLite creates it on connect.
Below is a very simple but functioning example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ZConnection1.Protocol := 'sqlite-3';
    ZConnection1.Database := 'foo.s3db';
    if not FileExists('foo.s3db') then
    begin
        ZConnection1.Connect;
        ZConnection1.ExecuteDirect('create table foo (bar integer)');
    end
    else
        ZConnection1.Connect;
    ZConnection1.Disconnect;
end;
```